# PHP Word Moderation

Tags: php, html

I am building an automatic word moderation for the Discussion Forum that I am creating for a project. The automatic word moderation that I have right now works perfectly fine except if the input is not the exact same word as I put on the array. So say 'happy' is the word that I've put on the array, 'Happy' with the capital H will not be detected. Below is the code that I used.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$banned = array('shit','fuck','bastard','cunt', 'fuck you', 'piss'); 
$entry = $_POST['reply_content'];
mb_strtolower($banned);
foreach($banned as $word):
if (strpos($entry, $word) !== false){
    echo 'Please use a more appropriate language.';
        exit;
} 
endforeach;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stripos()` is what you need then, instead of `strpos()`.

The `i` is for case insensitivity.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Answer (score 0):

There's always a way around the filter (H4PPY), but this will ignore caps and block the word anyway

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$banned = array('shit','fuck','bastard','cunt', 'fuck you', 'piss'); 
$entry = strtolower(htmlentities(($_POST['reply_content'])));
mb_strtolower($banned);
foreach($banned as $word):
if($word == $entry) {
    echo 'Please use a more appropriate language.';
    exit;
}
endforeach;
}
```